# remove certain key from a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, syntax

I have a list contains dictionaries

```
[{'item1':xxx, 'item2':xxx}, {'item1':xxx, 'item2':xxx}]
```

I want to remove all 'item1' so the list becomes:

```
['item2':xxx}, {'item2':xxx}]
```

What is the shortest syntax I could use? I know you can loop it through using for ...but I am looking for the simplest syntax! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest syntax *is* a for loop.

```
for D in L:
  del D['item1']
```